# Take screenshot on command prompt/powershell

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe, screenshot

I want my script to get a screenshot using command prompt/powershell **WITHOUT ANY 3RD PARTY TOOLS** how can I do that it should look like this `"C:\Windows\System32\screenshot.exe" "C:\Users\%username%\Pictures\screenshot.png"`

Comment: What you describe does not exist. This can only be accomplished by third-party software.

Comment: With PowerShell, you have the full power of .NET Framework (or Core) available to you, surely you'll find something.

Comment: Windows has native keyboard shortcuts that you can utilize to create a screenshot and place it in the clipboard. All you need to do is send that to the taskbar and save the clipboard to a file. That said, SuperUser is not a script-writing service. If you post your script, we can help you with finding out why its not working, but we won't write a full script for you.

Comment: Just search for PowerShell Screenshot, the first link already tells you everything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guys I've found a way just replace urusername with your username and run this command

```ps1
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$Screen = [System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation]::VirtualScreen
$Width  = $Screen.Width
$Height = $Screen.Height
$Left   = $Screen.Left
$Top    = $Screen.Top

$bitmap  = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap $Width, $Height
$graphic = [System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($bitmap)
$graphic.CopyFromScreen($Left, $Top, 0, 0, $bitmap.Size)

$bitmap.Save("C:\Users\urusername\Desktop\MyFancyScreenshot.bmp")
Write-Output "Screenshot saved to:"
Write-Output C:\Users\urusername\Desktop\MyFancyScreenshot.bmp
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for a script for ease, You should instead use `Win + Shift + S` to open Snip and Sketch tool. It is very handy especially if you are a student and take screenshot every now and then.

With that been said, if you still want to take screenshots from command line, you can use the command: `explorer ms-screenclip:`. Save this as a batch file, and when you will run this script, this will launch the Snip and Sketch tool in Snipping mode.

Comment: Though you can send the keycode for most keys (see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709474/sendkeys-from-command-prompt), apparently sending PrtSc is not as simple: https://handmade.network/forums/t/2011-keyboard_inputs_-_scancodes,_raw_input,_text_input,_key_names

Comment: The author wants to take the screenshot not simply launch an application that is capable of taking a screenshot. I have my doubts this answer's the author's question.

Comment: Thanks for your work guys! I already found a way out though.

Comment: @TheCodeExpert Pleaswe if you have found a solution, post it as self-answer so others may benefit as well. If the solution came from somewhere, include a link to the original.